# Why do my grid panel events stop firing in ExtJS 4?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, extjs4.2

I'm working on a legacy `ExtJS 4.2.1` project.

Within the app, I have a class that extends `Ext.window.Window`.
The class(window) contains several `Ext.grid.Panel` objects.

Within each grid panel, I have some listeners like:

```
listeners: {
    select: function(..) {
        console.log('hello!');
    }
}
```

When the window is first instantiated and shown, all of the events fire just fine for each grid panel as I'm clicking the rows.

However, the second time I open the window, none of the grid panel's events fire at all.

Each grid panel has the following selection model:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    allowDeselect: false,
    checkOnly: true,
    ignoreRightMouseSelection: true,
    injectCheckbox: 0
}),
selType: 'checkboxmodel',
```

I can show more code snippets if needed but I can't find anything that's out of the ordinary.  Meaning, I'm not aware of anything bizarre or custom we're doing that would override any default behavior.

Any information would be appreciated.